# Integer in object inside array not decreasing

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, integer, timeout

I made this code that when run adds one value to the mzone to a maximum of 3, and that five seconds later should decrease the value that was added, but this last part isn't working. I am still learning so I don't know what might be wrong.

```js
    clubsList[playerCountry].mzone = (clubsList[playerCountry].mzone + 1) || 1; //This works perfectly. It adds 1 to the mzone everytime it's run.
    console.log(clubsList[playerCountry].mzone)
    setTimeout(function(){ (clubsList[playerCountry].mzone - 1 ) }, 5000); //This isn't working
    setTimeout(function(){ (console.log(clubsList[playerCountry].mzone)) }, 6000);
```

The completed code:

```js
clubsList = []

onNet('verifyMeetingZone', (playerCountry) => {
    if (!clubsList[playerCountry]) {
        clubsList[playerCountry] = {}
        clubsList[playerCountry].mzone = 0
    }
    // HERE
    if (clubsList[playerCountry].mzone <= 2) {
        console.log("Mzone Criado")  
        clubsList[playerCountry].mzone = (clubsList[playerCountry].mzone + 1) || 1; 
        console.log(clubsList[playerCountry].mzone)
        setTimeout(function(){ (clubsList[playerCountry].mzone - 1 ) }, 5000);
        setTimeout(function(){ (console.log(clubsList[playerCountry].mzone)) }, 6000);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Ja existe")  
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not re-assigining the changed value back to the object is why the object is not picking up the decrement:

```
 setTimeout(function(){ clubsList[playerCountry].mzone = clubsList[playerCountry].mzone - 1  }, 5000);
```

Try this out, it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I should change this:

```js
    setTimeout(function(){ (clubsList[playerCountry].mzone - 1 ) }, 5000);
```

to this:

```js
    setTimeout(function(){ (clubsList[playerCountry].mzone = clubsList[playerCountry].mzone - 1) }, 5000);
```